# Store result of SQL query in PHP $variable

Tags: php, sql, variables, save, sum

I want to save the result of my query (result of sum of all lines for 1 column) in PHP variable.
Example of my table :

```
CONSO_1 | CONSO_2
  15    |   10
  25    |    2
  54    |   45
  ..    |   ..
```

I want to sum all lines for `CONSO_1` and * 12. Normally my query is OK.

But I want to store the result (here : (15+25+54)*12= 1128) in PHP $variable.

My query :

> $query = "Select SUM(CONSO_1) * 12 AS CONSO_Total_1, SUM(CONSO_2) * 25 FROM test WHERE
>   DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE(NOW())";

Can you help me please ?

Comment: In this case I want to have : $variable = 1128 (= CONSO_Total_1)

Comment: Solved ! :)
$result = mysql_query($query); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $sumCONSO = $row['CONSO_Total_1'];

Comment: But now I have this error : PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean. This line : $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: You providing not enough detalis. Also, there is a [question about your error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1):

use this query and store result in a var

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(CONSO_1) FROM table_name";
```

This will return the sum of all values from `CONSO_1 col`.